# Class X not have attributes Y

Tags: python, list

I don't understand this strange things...I've this class:

```py
class cChallenge:
    def __init__(self, Id:int = 0 , Difficulty:str = '', Title:str = '',
                 Challenge:str = '', Url:str = '', Solved:bool = False):
        self.Id = Id
        self.Difficulty = Difficulty
        self.Title = Title
        self.Challenge = Challenge
        self.Url = Url
        self.Solved = Solved
```

Everything works fine so I've pushed all my generated `cChallenge` elements into a list: `cList`.
If I query the list for single object everything works fine:

```py
print(cList[1].Id)
>> 380
```

but if I use list comp:

```py
print([x.Id for x in cList])
>> AttributeError: type object 'cChallenge' has no attribute 'Id'
```

[https://pastebin.com/cGuhPAG8] That's the link if someone want to try

Comment: It looks like you never instantiated `cChallenge` but you are using the class itself.

Comment: How did you *define* `cList`?

Comment: Just because *one* element of the list is an instance of `cChallenge` doesn't necessarily mean *all* elements are.

Comment: Check your list with: print([type(x) for x in cList])

Comment: you should look into the `dataclasses` library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: @EricMarchand I've try the result is: `<class '__main__.cChallenge'>, <class 'type'>`. How can I extract the second? I've try with `..type(x) != "<class '__main__cChallenge,>` but it seems not work

Comment: @chepner Hi! yes you're right but if I point to a `cChallenge.Id` and everything works fine I can't understand why the error say `cChallenge has no attribute Id`

Comment: @LorenzoMonaco You constructed the list incorrectly. The *type* `cChallenge` itself doesn't belong there, most likely. Again, how did you *define* `clist` in the first place?

Comment: Put another way, the question isn't how to get the `Id` attribute from something that doesn't have it, but rather what is `cChallenge` doing in a list of *instances* of `cChallenge` in the first place?

Comment: What are "attributes Y"?

Comment: [https://pastebin.com/cGuhPAG8] That's the link to the code, please no shame on me for the code format, I'm just trying to test the psaw API.

Answer (score 0):

In the code of the complete script to fill the list you need to create an instance of a class i.e. each object (look at added variable `c`):

```
for s in submission:
#other code...
                c = cChallenge(Id, Difficulty, '', Url, Solved)
                cList.append(c)
#other code...
```

Don't know exactly what are you trying to put into the list, but probably this will do.

Comment: thanks @Alecx This solved the problem, I've refactor the come a little bit of time and I've forgot to create the instance!

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Alecx note

> to fill the list you need to create an instance of a class

so the right code for who look inside the pastebin is:

```py
for s in submission
   ...
   _ = cChallenge(...)
   cList.append(_)
```

I will post the github link to the project tomorrow for who is interested!